# Implementing a dual-click control with CSS/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to implement a dual-click control that reveals the action on the first click and allows launching the action on an optional second click. This part is easy and I've done it (see code below). As is, the first action is removed after the first click and the second action is attached. However, if the user doesn't want to proceed after the first action, I would like the widgets to revert back to the initial state so they can do the reveal-first, act-second sequence at a later time. I can't figure out an elegant way of doing this. Suggestions (or even alternative ways of implementing this) welcome.

```js
const first = (e) => {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation()
    e.target.removeEventListener('click', first)
    e.target.addEventListener('click', second)
}

const second = (e) => {
    console.log(`${e.target.getAttribute('data-val')} ${e.target.id}`)
}

const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.semafore')

btns.forEach(b => { b.addEventListener('click', first) })
```

```css
.semafores { display: block; width: auto; height: 40px; }
.r { background: red; }
.g { background: green; }
.b { background: blue; }

.semafore {
    float: left;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 15px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: white;
    transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out, color 0.2s;
}
.semafore.r:focus,
.semafore.g:focus,
.semafore.b:focus { width: auto; padding: 0 10px; }
.semafore.r:focus::after,
.semafore.g:focus::after,
.semafore.b:focus::after { content: attr(data-val); }
```

```html
<div class="semafores">
    <button id="1r" data-val='remove' class="r semafore"></button>
    <button id="1g" data-val='change' class="g semafore"></button>
    <button id="1b" data-val='report' class="b semafore"></button>
</div>

<div class="semafores">
    <button id="2r" data-val='remove' class="r semafore"></button>
    <button id="2g" data-val='change' class="g semafore"></button>
    <button id="2b" data-val='report' class="b semafore"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: See [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

Comment: by the way, how do I select an element to attach an event so it would work in the code snippet editor? specifically, how do I make this work? `const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.semafore'); btns.forEach(b => { b.addEventListener('click', first) })`?

Comment: You may consider asking about this proposed interaction in the [User Experience Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @punkish I answered your question. Please give a feedback...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `reset()` function.

---

## With two different event listeners:

(*like in your example*)

```js
const reset = () => {
    btns.forEach(btn => {
        btn.removeEventListener('click', second);
        btn.addEventListener('click', first);
    });
};
```

You would call it before you change the event listeners in `first()` or before your `console.log()` in `second()`,

```js
const first = (e) => {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    reset();
    e.target.removeEventListener('click', first);
    e.target.addEventListener('click', second);
};

const second = (e) => {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    reset();
    console.log(`${e.target.getAttribute('data-val')} ${e.target.id}`);
};
```

or if you click outside of a `button.semafore`.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', reset);
```

**Working example:**

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.semafore');

const reset = () => {
    btns.forEach(btn => {
        btn.removeEventListener('click', second);
        btn.addEventListener('click', first);
    });
};

const first = (e) => {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    reset();
    e.target.removeEventListener('click', first);
    e.target.addEventListener('click', second);
};

const second = (e) => {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    reset();
    console.log(`${e.target.getAttribute('data-val')} ${e.target.id}`);
};

btns.forEach(b => { b.addEventListener('click', first); });

document.addEventListener('click', reset);
```

```css
.semafores { display: block; width: auto; height: 40px; }

.r { background: red; }
.g { background: green; }
.b { background: blue; }

.semafore {
    float: left;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 15px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: white;
    transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out, color 0.2s;
}

.semafore.r:focus,
.semafore.g:focus,
.semafore.b:focus { width: auto; padding: 0 10px; }

.semafore.r:focus::after,
.semafore.g:focus::after,
.semafore.b:focus::after { content: attr(data-val); }
```

```html
<div class="semafores">
    <button id="1r" data-val='remove' class="r semafore"></button>
    <button id="1g" data-val='change' class="g semafore"></button>
    <button id="1b" data-val='report' class="b semafore"></button>
</div>

<div class="semafores">
    <button id="2r" data-val='remove' class="r semafore"></button>
    <button id="2g" data-val='change' class="g semafore"></button>
    <button id="2b" data-val='report' class="b semafore"></button>
</div>
```

---

## With data attributes:

```js
const reset = () => {
    const active_btn = document.querySelector('[data-active="true"]');
    if (active_btn) {
        active_btn.dataset.active = 'false';
    }
};
```

You could handle both clicks in one handler:

```js
const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    if (e.target.dataset.active == 'true') {
        reset();
        console.log(`${e.target.getAttribute('data-val')} ${e.target.id}`);
    }
    else { 
        reset();
        e.target.dataset.active = 'true';
    }
};
```

**Working example:**

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.semafore');

const reset = () => {
    const active_btn = document.querySelector('[data-active="true"]');
    if (active_btn) {
        active_btn.dataset.active = 'false';
    }
};

const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    if (e.target.dataset.active == 'true') {
        reset();
        console.log(`${e.target.getAttribute('data-val')} ${e.target.id}`);
    }
    else { 
        reset();
        e.target.dataset.active = 'true';
    }
};

btns.forEach(b => { b.addEventListener('click', handleClick); });

document.addEventListener('click', reset);
```

```css
.semafores { display: block; width: auto; height: 40px; }

.r { background: red; }
.g { background: green; }
.b { background: blue; }

.semafore {
    float: left;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 15px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: white;
    transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out, color 0.2s;
}

.semafore.r:focus,
.semafore.g:focus,
.semafore.b:focus { width: auto; padding: 0 10px; }

.semafore.r:focus::after,
.semafore.g:focus::after,
.semafore.b:focus::after { content: attr(data-val); }
```

```html
<div class="semafores">
    <button id="1r" data-val='remove' data-active="false" class="r semafore"></button>
    <button id="1g" data-val='change' data-active="false" class="g semafore"></button>
    <button id="1b" data-val='report' data-active="false" class="b semafore"></button>
</div>

<div class="semafores">
    <button id="2r" data-val='remove' data-active="false" class="r semafore"></button>
    <button id="2g" data-val='change' data-active="false" class="g semafore"></button>
    <button id="2b" data-val='report' data-active="false" class="b semafore"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: I've marked this as the answer because it does work. However, I have decided to do more research on how to handle this kind of behavior on touch screen vs mouse interface before I implement something. Many thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

How about making it this way? Instead of having two events we can make one with state:

```js
const event = (e) => {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation()
    var state = e.target.dataset['state']
    if(state === 'first') {
      e.target.dataset['state'] = 'second'
      first(e)
    } else {
      second(e)
    }
}

const first = (e) => {
    console.log(`first ${e.target.getAttribute('data-val')} ${e.target.id}`)
}

const second = (e) => {
    console.log(`second ${e.target.getAttribute('data-val')} ${e.target.id}`)
}

const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.semafore')

btns.forEach(b => { b.addEventListener('click', event) })
```

```css
.semafores { display: block; width: auto; height: 40px; }
.r { background: red; }
.g { background: green; }
.b { background: blue; }

.semafore {
    float: left;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 15px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: white;
    transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out, color 0.2s;
}
.semafore.r:focus,
.semafore.g:focus,
.semafore.b:focus { width: auto; padding: 0 10px; }
.semafore.r:focus::after,
.semafore.g:focus::after,
.semafore.b:focus::after { content: attr(data-val); }
```

```html
<div class="semafores">
<button id="1r" data-state="first" data-val='remove' class="r semafore"></button>
<button id="1g" data-state="first" data-val='change' class="g semafore"></button>
<button id="1b" data-state="first" data-val='report' class="b semafore"></button>
</div>

<div class="semafores">
<button id="2r" data-state="first" data-val='remove' class="r semafore"></button>
<button id="2g" data-state="first" data-val='change' class="g semafore"></button>
<button id="2b" data-state="first" data-val='report' class="b semafore"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: but how does this help solve my problem? Imagine, a user clicks on a red button. It expands to show what it can do. But the user doesn't click again on the expanded red button. Instead, the user does something else, perhaps clicks on the green light, or just clicks outside on the document. The red button shrinks back to a circle but the second state is still attached to it. Then the user clicks the red button again. Now, instead of expanding (like the original action), it fires the second action right away. What I want is for the state to revert back the first.